# Is it possible to return the value from subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, ngx-translate

this is my translate function, i require to return the array. Is it possible to return from `Subscribe` - ?

```
translator(items) {
        const output = items?.map((item) => {
            return this.translate.get(item.label).subscribe((value) => {
                item = { ...item, label: value };
                return item;
            });
        });
        console.log('output', output);//no data
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to do the following:

1. enrich each item in the `items` array
2. convert it to a promise
3. await this promise
4. print the output of this promise

You can use the following code in order to achive this:

```
async translator(items) {
    const output = await lastValueFrom(
      forkJoin(
        items?.map((item) =>
          this.translate
            .get(item.label)
            .pipe(map((value) => ({ ...item, label: value })))
        )
      )
    );

    console.log('output', output); //no data
  }
```

Explanation:

- `lastValueFrom` is used to convert an observable stream to a promise (and return the last value)
- `forkJoin` is used to subscribe to multiple observables and emit the result array after each of them have completed
- `map` is used to "enrich" the initial items